# Electrical code - Conduit requirements for 50A copper cable through outside wall

Tags: electrical, conduit

Can anyone advise what (if any) sized conduit one has to use per code to have a 50A copper cable run from inside through an outside, concrete, wall? I live in Maryland, USA, if that is helpful.

Would be extra helpful if a link to an online copy of section of the electrical code that stipulated the requirements in the above regard could be provided in an answer.

Comment: There are no stable online copies of the Electrical Code, the only ones are behind a paywall (or to be more precise, a signupwall).

Comment: Is the conduit run all the way from the service panel to the receptacle? Is it metal conduit? **Will you ever put any other wire or cable in the conduit?**

Comment: @Harper - Wasn't intending to have conduit on the inside run, just read that it is required through the concrete wall + any outside section of cable that is not behind at socket/junction/etc. Wasn't sure if metal, plastic, or something else was required in the way of conduit, which was part of the question. Lastly, no, don't intend to feed anything else through the conduit, especially as it is my understanding there is a safety reason for having conduit, and of a certain % above the cable size, in the first place.

Comment: Ok, so that's "conduit as a local physical-damage shield for the NM or UF wiring method", not "conduit as a wiring method". Changes the numbers.

Comment: @Harper - Sorry, yes, physical damage is what I was thinking about when writing the question. Hoping you can provide an answer to the question now, but happy to clarify any further questions me not being familiar with the NEC, don't know are important.